# How can I use 3 letter hreflang?

Tags: html, multilingual, meta-tags, hreflang

I can't seem to find any information on this online

I have a few use cases for supporting some ISO 639-2/3 (3 letter) language codes in pages (less well known language variants)

According to all the documentation I can find, hreflang tags only support ISO 639-1 (2 letter) language codes. That is fine if so, I guess standards take time...

But how could I organise my meta tags to indicate that it is the same page, but in a 3 letter language code?

Comment: You can read [RFC 5646 section 3.1 Syntax](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5646#section-2.1) to read about all possible language codes for the `hreflang` attribute of a link with a `href` attribute.

Comment: Thanks, from that I cannot determine whether it would be better to use "incorrect" tags in the hopes of future compatibility (i.e. using 3 letter hreflang) or to just treat the page as a separate page even though it is just a language version of an existing page

Comment: Well, it says you should use the _"shortest ISO 639 code"_. That means a two letter code, unless none is available, then you can use a three letter code. For a list of these codes see: [Library of Congress](https://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php). So you can use three letter codes for languages that aren't in ISO 639-1.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful - Google makes out that only 2 letter codes must be used. I know they aren't officially the authority on these things, but they kind of are... https://developers.google.com/search/docs/specialty/international/localized-versions#language-codes